# How to extract value from html tag attributes in Django

Tags: python, html, django, web-scraping

I am practicing scraping imdb new coming movies, to be more specific I like to get the name, src, title and so on of the movie list, however, what I'm getting is this..

[, ,...]

I have tried to extract the value many ways but no success.

m.img.title  m['title'] m.get('title') and others similar

<< my views.py file >>

```
    def movies(request):
        import requests
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
        headers.update({ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'})
        url = "https://www.imdb.com/movies-in-theaters/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2413b25e-e3f6-4229-9efd-599bb9ab1f97&pf_rd_r=TVZT5ZEDG4QTR3X0H40R&pf_rd_s=right-2&pf_rd_t=15061&pf_rd_i=homepage&ref_=hm_otw_sm"
        req = requests.get(url, headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
        movies = soup.find_all('img', attrs={"class": "poster shadowed"})
        return render(request, 'movies.html', {'movies': movies})
```

<< my movie.html >>
        {% extends 'base.html' %}

```
    {% block content %}

    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-light">
      {% for m in movies %}
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th width="10" scope="row">{{ how to extract the src }}</th>
          <th width="10" scope="row">{{ how to extract the alt }}</th>
          <th width="10" scope="row">{{ how to extract the title }}</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <br/>

    {{ movies }}

    {% endblock %}
```

<< my output from localhost:8000/movies/ >>

[, ,...]

I'd like to extract the value for src, alt, title and put it in each cell

```
  <tr>
    <th width="10" scope="row">{{ m['src'] }}</th>
    <th width="10" scope="row">{{ m['alt'] }}</th>
    <th width="10" scope="row">{{ m['title'] }}</th>
  </tr>
```

Comment: are you just looking to parse the html data? in that case this would help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: this question is more about scraping than django. i'd suggest re-tagging this for better feedback.  In terms of scraping, you're going about the parsing in bs4 incorrectly.  You should inspect the elements in the imdb page and hierarchically drill down until you find the data you want, and then save it into a dictionary or list. raw bs4 parse is usually not good output.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Stackoverflow, so I didn't know I got some responses. My progress so far...I got return as follows:

[<img alt="Ford v Ferrari (2019) Poster" class="poster shadowed" height="209" src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYzcyZDNlNDktOWRhYy00ODQ5LTg1ODQtZmFmZTIyMjg2Yjk5XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTkxNjUyNQ@@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg" title="Ford v Ferrari (2019)" width="140"/>]


This is the best I could do, however, I don't know how to drill down further, can some one point it out for me.